# What flavour of ubuntu desktop should I use?

Tags: desktop-environments

I have a powerpc, 800mhz 832mb of ram.  Currently running Mac OSX tiger.

I have tried Ubuntu 10.04 and it's way too slow.  Xubuntu is also too slow for regular usage (gui elements lag a lot).

Which Ubuntu desktop flavor should I use?

Comment: alexy13 - lubuntu is the way to go - ubuntuforums has an excellent how-to guide.  I recommend you have a read of this.  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1798792

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), designed to be lightweight and not resource heavy.

You might need to work a little to install it on a PPC architecture though. [Here's](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1454430) a thread with some of the details on that.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with you. Lubuntu is really cool. Amazingle user friendly if you consider how little resources it requires.

Answer (score 2):

Xubuntu is also another great lightweight flavor of Ubuntu. It uses the Xfce Desktop Environment. The minimum RAM requirement for Xubuntu is 192MB and 256MB is recommended, so you should be more than fine with 832MB.

If you install Ubuntu and run the Classic Desktop (the desktop used in 10.04) with no effects and find that it's still too slow, you could try running another session with a different Desktop Environment.

This may be of some help to you: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/config-desktop/C/other-desktops.html :]

Hope this helps.